# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method is not implemented by JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

My Driver Oracle version is 10.2.0.4.0.

My Object is mapped with:

```
@Lob @Column(name="allegato") private String allegato;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a newer driver, since Lob support has been added in the driver 11.1:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcvers.htm#BCFFIFAD

> Support for JDBC 4.0 Standard
> The JDBC 4.0 standard support is provided by JDK 1.6 and later versions. Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1) JDBC drivers provide support for the JDBC 4.0 standard.
>
> Some of the new features available in Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1) JDBC drivers are the following:
> Wrapper Pattern Support
>
> - Enhanced Exception Hierarchy and SQLException
> - The RowId Data Type
> - LOB Creation
> - National Language Character Set Support